# how to sqlDrop an existing query (not table!) in R // delete existing query that is stored in an Access database

Tags: r, ms-access, rodbc

I often use RODBC to work with MS Access files in R. For removing existing tables sqlDrop works fine, e.g.:

```
db <- odbcConnectAccess(choose.files(caption="select database"))
sqlDrop(db, "existing_dummy_table")
```

What I need to do now is to delete an existing query that is stored in the Access database. sqlDrop does only seem to work with tables, not with querys.

```
sqlDrop(db, "existing_dummy_query")
```

brings up:

```
Error in odbcTableExists(channel, sqtable, abort = errors) : 
  ‘existing_dummy_query’: table not found on channel
```

Is there any solution how to delete/remove existing queries?

Thank you!

Comment: No, not via ODBC. You will need to open Access via automation to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Gustav! After a lot of testing I found a soultion myself: `sqlQuery(db, "DROP TABLE existing_dummy_query;")` Maybe its helpful for others. DROP VIEW did not work. I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing I found a soultion myself:

```
sqlQuery(db, "DROP TABLE existing_dummy_query";)
```

Maybe its helpful for others. DROP VIEW did not work. I don't know why.